# How to add sharepoint urls to language studio

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, azure-qna-maker

Unsupported/Invalid URL(s):

I tried replacing %20 with space but that didn't work.
Also i tried removing query string from url i.e. ?----)

still the unsupprorted url and invalid url message is displayed .
PLease help how to resolve this issue.